# How to merge a video vertically by taking specific time slots from two different videos with a single ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have three ffmpeg commands. Two of those commands will trim the input videos and the third will merge into a single video.

I want to run them as a single command instead of three, which consumes a lot of time because I'm taking output of the 1st and 2nd videos individually.

Instead, I want to take specific parts from the videos which I need and merge them as a single video.

The commands which I use for singie videos trim:-

```
ffmpeg -y -i video1.mp4 -ss 4 -t 10000 -qscale:v 8 -strict -2 video1out.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i video2.mp4 -ss 4 -t 10000 -qscale:v 8 -strict -2 video2out.mp4

ffmpeg -i video1out.mp4 -i video2out.mp4 -filter_complex vstack -strict -2 merge.mp4
```

Comment: Maybe, glue the commands together with '&&' ? Like this:
`ffmpeg -y -i video1.mp4 -ss 4 -t 10000 -qscale:v 8 -strict -2 video1out.mp4 && ffmpeg -y -i video2.mp4 -ss 4 -t 10000 -qscale:v 8 -strict -2 video2out.mp4 && ffmpeg -i video1out.mp4 -i video2out.mp4 -filter_complex vstack -strict -2 merge.mp4`. But I'm not sure if you're using the terminal and on which platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -ss 4 -t 10000 -i video1.mp4 -ss 4 -t 10000 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex vstack -c:a copy merge.mp4`

`-strict -2` hasn't been required for AAC encoder use since 2016. You should upgrade ffmpeg.